# Whenever I switch on my UPS, can I make my PC boot automatically without push power button?

Tags: windows-10, boot, hardware-failure

Whenever I switch on my UPS, can I make my PC boot automatically without push power button?

Comment: How was the PC  shutdown?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the action in your BIOS/UEFI. It should look similar:

[image: BIOS Last Power state]

Select "Power On", save and it should work.

Comment: Will this work if the PC was powered down, or only if it lost power while on?

Comment: I changed the picture to make it more clear.